# Remove string from string jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ignore my novice knowledge in jQuery. I started to learn recently and I have a challenge in front of me. I have a checkbox with names checkbox_0, checkbox_1 and want to remove "checkbox_" from the strings so that I would use the 0, 1 in my loop to extract the data for that index. Thanks

aData value alerts me the value checkbox_0, checkbox_1 etc. those are the checkboxes selected.

```
submitButton.on("click", function() {
           $("Table :checked").each(function(e) {
                var iData =Table.fnGetData( this.parentNode);
                // Strip of the checkbox_ from the string
                for(var i=0; i<=iData.length; i++) {
                  aData = iData[i][7];
                }
                alert(aData);
                Table.fnDraw();             
                 
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is just a JavaScript, not a jQuery, thing.

To remove the first occurence of the work "checkbox_":

```
var updatedString = originalString.replace("checkbox_", "");
```

Or if you know it'll always be in the form `"checkbox_n"` where `n` is a digit,

```
var updatedString = originalString.substring(9);
```

...which chops the first nine characters off the string.

In either case, you end up with a string. If you want a number, you can use `parseInt`:

```
var updatedString = parseInt(originalString.replace("checkbox_", ""), 10);
// or
var updatedString = parseInt(originalString.substring(9), 10);
```

...or just put a `+` in front of it to cause an automatic cast (but note that in that case, both decimal and hex strings will be handled):

```
var updatedString = +originalString.replace("checkbox_", "");
// or
var updatedString = +originalString.substring(9);
```

---

Note that I've written `updatedString = originalString.blah(...);` but of course you can replace your reference, e.g., "originalString = originalString.blah(...);`.

More to explore:

- [MDN page on `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: can also do : originalString = originalString.replace('checkbox_','');

Comment: That was easy and quick thank you verymuch. I have another question though, can I accumulate all the checkboxes that have been selected and then send all those values as a single ajax call instead for each? I have Table.fnDraw() which does single ajax call for the each row selected

Answer (score 3):

```
submitButton.on("click", function() {
           $("Table :checked").each(function(e) {
                var iData =Table.fnGetData( this.parentNode);
                // Strip of the checkbox_ from the string
                for(var i=0; i<=iData.length; i++) {
                  aData = iData[i].replace("checkbox_", "");
                }
                alert(aData);
                Table.fnDraw();             

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `checkbox_` part, you can simply do this:

```
cbName=cbName.replace("checkbox_", "");
```

To do this for all your checkboxes inside the `.each()` loop:

```
var cbIndex=this.name.replace("checkbox_", "");
//or...
var cbIndex=this.name.split("checkbox_").join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, some of them:

```
$("table :checked").each(function() {
    var theNumber = this.name.replace(/\D/g, "");
    var theNumber = this.name.replace(/[^\d]/g, ""); // or this
    var theNumber = this.name.match(/\d/g).join();   // or this
```